# C# - Draw graphics to a fullscreen DirectX application

Tags: c#, directx, hook

I am trying to draw graphics to a DirectX app (CS:GO).
I am using this code to draw in desktop:

```
IntPtr desktopPtr = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(desktopPtr);
SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
g.FillEllipse(b, new Rectangle(new Point(0,0), new Size(50, 50)));
Thread.Sleep(10);
g.Dispose();
ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, desktopPtr);
```

(in a loop)

it works fine if application is on windowed mode. But when I switch it to fullscreen mode, I am unable to draw graphics.
I tried setting hWnd to application's hWnd instead of zero, but no luck.
I think I need to inject something. Any ideas?

Comment: This is how the wh got started

Comment: @MarkBenovsky ssshh :P actually a bomb timer, but if I can get this to work I will change wh code to graphics draw

Comment: In full screen directx you will need to inject into the target and hook the directx present. Take a squizz at Direct3DHook on GitHub